# Remove buggy bottom padding in Gboard

Tags: gboard

My phone woke up in my pocket, I don't know how long, and now I have this big margin in Gboard.

[image]

All other functionalities look ok. Tried rebooting, but no luck there. The phone is a Poco X5 Pro.

How can I fix my keyboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like **a new keyboard resizing feature introduced since Gboard 13.2.05.x.**

According to [9to5Google - Gboard rolling out an easier way to ‘Resize’ and customize your keyboard](https://9to5google.com/2023/08/02/gboard-resize-android/),

> “Resize” appears as another toolbar/tray option. Tapping takes you to a UI that starts by letting you make Gboard taller or shorter, [...]
>
> [...]
>
> If you’re not taking up all the available space, you can move the keyboard. **If you drag it up, you’ll see empty space beneath the last row/spacebar.** [...]

<sup>(Emphasis added)</sup>